# What is the significance of an ODE being linear?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, linear-transformations

The concept of "linearity" has multiple meanings in different contexts.

Let me compare linearity of ODE's to lineairity of operators

When we say that a particular operator is linear, such as the derivative operator, this has a very clear significance: It means that we can "split" the derivative into multiple additive components:
$$\frac{d}{dx}(f+g)=\frac{d}{dx}f+\frac{d}{dx}g$$
This makes our calculation a lot easier, since if we know the derivative of f and g separately, we know their sum. Since the derivative operator is **not** linear with respect to multiplication, $\frac{d}{dx}(f\cdot g)$ is more complex.

> In sum: the significance of linearity of an operator is that it allows
>   us to split the operator and afterwards add the results, which very
>   much simplifies computation

**What would be a similar description of the significance of linearity of an ODE?**

Comment: It's more of a definition on the form of an ode, though linear equations are often much easier to solve and often have extra nice qualities like the linearity of their solutions, which is known as the principle of linear superposition

Comment: The phrase "linear with respect to multiplication" is meaningless; the term you are looking for is "distributive". Linearity = distributivity over addition + commutativity with scalar multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

Let's write a differential equation, be it ordinary or partial, as $Of=g$ for some operator $O$. As you already know, we call $O$ linear if $O(\sum_i a_i f_i)=\sum_i a_i Of_i$ for constants $a_i$ and functions $f_i$. In this case we also call the equation linear, and we note that if $f=f_i$ are solutions then so is $\sum_i a_i f_i$ provided $\sum_i a_i =1$ (or, if $g$ = 0, in which case we say the equation is homogeneous, we can drop this constraint).

Homogeneous linear equations' solution sets are therefore vector spaces specifiable by identifying a basis, and in some cases we can prove some set of solutions is a complete basis. Sometimes, one can prove a given finite set's size is the dimension of the vector space of solutions (for example, you can use this when solving $f''=-k^2 f$). Another strategy, which often yields fruit even for infinite-dimensional solution sets, is to use an integral transform, which can also be helpful with inhomogeneous linear equations.

If $Of_0=g$ the set of choices for $f-f_0$ satisfying $Of=g$ is a vector space, so you can think of the solutions of $Of=g$ as a translated subspace. We call $f-f_0$ (whose possible values don't depend on the choice of $g$) a complementary function and $f_0$ (which could be any solution consistent with the given $g$) a particular integral. As a simple example, for $f'=m$ we can take $f_0=mx$ to be our particular integral, while the complementary function is any constant. To take a more general example, if functions $P,\,Q,\,R,\,S$ satisfy $R'=RP,\,S'=RQ$ then $f'+Pf=Q$ has solution $f=R^{-1}(S+c)$ for constant $c$, so the complementary function is $cR^{-1}$ while the particular integral is $SR^{-1}$.

Comment: You might want to either be a little less notation heavy or otherwise show how the OP's simple cases of linearity generalize to your summation equality and the rest of the first paragraph. From there, your post is a great read for those who understand it, but might be a bit too notation-heavy for someone with perhaps minimal background in linear algebra and maybe Multivariable calculus. Otherwise this is a fantastic answer!